# website not working :-403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: apache2

One of my website is showing 403 forbidden error.

all the permission in document root are 755 and ownership of user and group www-data.

configuration file is.

```
 directory /var/www/public_html>

   AddHandler fcgid-script  .php

  Options +ExecCGI +Includes +Indexes

  AllowOverride All

  FCGIWrapper /var/www/php.fcgi .php

  /directory>
```

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing it wrong.

Should not be only this?

```
<Directory /var/www/public_html>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    Options +ExecCGI +Includes +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

If only this does work, should se the fgci.conf on apache modules

Some error logging would be nice as well.